# Is there a good application for Mac to manage subscriptions billings? 

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is there a good software for mac to manage subscriptions billings ?

I need to be payed regularly by my customers.
I need warnings service sending emails to them and me.

And I need to automize the payment process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not 100% clear what is the meaning of “automatize the payment process” but a very popular Mac application for billings is called… [Billings](http://www.marketcircle.com/billings/).

There are a few “comparison” reviews out there and you will not have a hard time finding there. Some are more extense (and outdated) and [others](http://freelanceswitch.com/product-reviews/mac-billing-application-round-up/) are short and concise. There are also some [round-ups](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/finance-roundups/7-invoicing-apps-for-os-x/) about invoicing apps (which are usually married with billings apps).

I personally use [GrandTotal](http://mediaatelier.com/GrandTotal/) ($) because I needed an Invoicing app for my little company. You can try most if not all of the applications for a few days before deciding which one is for you (or usually which one is “the closest” to what you want, because they all have stuff you don’t need and lack something you wish they had…).

Comment: Yeah I have Billings. But what I actually need is to manage customers subscriptions. I need to send them reminders every 6 months for example. And It would be great if the system informs me when a customer stops to pay me on my bank account

Comment: @Patrick I’m not sure if there’s an automated system for that. I use MoneyWell for the bank and GrandTotals for the invoices (which reminds me when invoices are recurrent and such), but I have to manually tell the program that an invoice is paid.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be something online like toggle.com.

Personally, I would say your best bet, however, would be MarketCircle Billings. It's an nice app that has an iPhone companion. It's about $40 online and you can get it from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I use Billings reoccurring invoice feature, but it doesn't integrate payment solutions.

Some Googling found these two links:

http://www.the10most.com/entrepreneurs/10-easy-recurring-billing-solutions.html

http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/15-great-apps-for-your-business-subscription-needs/

JBilling, though complex, could run locally on Apache on your Mac if you so desired, or hosted elsewhere and seems that is has lots of cool features.